# Several fields won't display

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, mysqli, echo

I have a single table named `Company`. It has five columns (`Company_ID`, `Company_Name`, `Product_Type`, `City` and `State`). Using a script I've repurposed for this assignment I can get `City` and `State` to display, but not `Company_Name` or `Product_Type`. I can't tell if they are invisible or not since I can still sort based on those two missing columns.

Here's the entire script:

```
<?php # Script 10.5 - #5
//....  
// Define the query:
$q = "SELECT Company_Name AS 'Company Name', Product_Type AS 'Product Type', City, State     FROM Company ORDER BY $order_by LIMIT $start, $display";       
$r = @mysqli_query ($dbc, $q); // Run the query.

// Table header
//....

// Fetch and print all the records....
$bg = '#eeeeee'; 
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $bg = ($bg=='#eeeeee' ? '#ffffff' : '#eeeeee');
        echo '<tr bgcolor="' . $bg . '">
        <td align="left"><a href="edit_user.php?id=' . $row['Company_Name'] .     '">Edit</a></td>
        <td align="left"><a href="delete_user.php?id=' . $row['Company_Name'] .     '">Delete</a></td>
        <td align="left">' . $row['Company_Name'] . '</td>
        <td align="left">' . $row['Product_Type'] . '</td>
        <td align="left">' . $row['City'] . '</td>
        <td align="left">' . $row['State'] . '</td>
    </tr>
    ';
} // End of WHILE loop.

echo '</table>';
mysqli_free_result ($r);
mysqli_close($dbc);
// ....
?>
```

I've run the same query from PHPMyAdmin and it's successful in that it shows all 7 records. Displaying the results seems to be the issue.

Comment: dont use @ to subside error remove and see the error that you get and you ran the query tats ok but have you fetch the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You select your rows like this:

```
$q = "SELECT Company_Name AS 'Company Name', Product_Type AS 'Product Type', [...] "
```

And then you try to access them with this:

```
<td align="left">' . $row['Company_Name'] . '</td>
<td align="left">' . $row['Product_Type'] . '</td>
```

But the names you used (`Company_Name` and `Product_Type`)  don't exist, since you specified a different name in your `as` statement, try:

```
$q = "SELECT Company_Name, Product_Type, [...] "
```

And it should work.

Comment: Wow. I feel dumb now. Thank you so much for taking the time to answer this. I'll check the box that this is answered in 3 minutes.